# Displaying array contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, text

I have loaded an array:

```
currentBackground=4;
bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_01 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_02 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_03 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_04 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_05 320x460"],
            nil];
```

Now I want to display in a label the file name of the image currently being displayed. I thought:

```
 mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bgImages= %@",[bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground]];
```

would work but all I get is hex code . I have a button that scrolls through the images very nicely. But when I try to display the image name all I get is what I believe to be the address where the name resides.

Thoughts.

Comment: What technologies are you using?  Retagging appropriately will help expose the question to the right audience, and result in better answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this - `[bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground]` - you are getting an instance of `UIImage`. And when you do your `stringWithFormat`, you're right that it's printing the address of the image and nothing more.

Unfortunately there's no way to get the "name" of the image back out of the `UIImage` instance so you would probably have to do something like this:

```
currentBackground=4;
bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_01 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_02 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_03 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_04 320x460"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mystery_05 320x460"],
            nil];
bgImageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"mystery_01 320x460",
                @"mystery_02 320x460",
                @"mystery_03 320x460",
                @"mystery_04 320x460",
                @"mystery_05 320x460",
                nil];
```

And then do:

```
mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bgImages= %@",[bgImageNames objectAtIndex:currentBackground]];
```

Or to wrap the creating of the `bgImages` array up a bit you could even be clever and do this:

```
currentBackground=4;
bgImageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"mystery_01 320x460",
                @"mystery_02 320x460",
                @"mystery_03 320x460",
                @"mystery_04 320x460",
                @"mystery_05 320x460",
                nil];
NSMutableArray *newBgImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *image in bgImageNames) {
    [newBgImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:image]];
}
bgImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newBgImages];
```

Comment: Thanks Matt this makes perfect sense.